# How to get the DateTime difference in Crystal Report

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, report

How can I get the DateTime difference between 2 DateTime fields in Crystal Report?

I tried using DateDiff with not much luck,

Any help/hint will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of Crystal Reports are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You are not giving that much info to help us solve your problem.

Getting no results with dateDiff might mean there is a Null value somewhere in your data.

At the 'File/Report Options' level, you have the possibility to 'convert Null values into default value' (this might not be the right translaction as I am not working with the english version of CR..). Select this option, so that Null dates in your database will be considered as dates in your function. Try to get your dateDiff result. If it still does not work, use a draft report to display all intermediate results in your function, or try to write it in Basic Syntax instead of Crystal Syntx.